# Why won't ejs loop through/recognize my data pulled from the mongodb schema?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, model-view-controller, callback, ejs

I'm trying to loop through the products in my products db and display each product as its own card on my site. The db contains 2 items and they won't show up on the page, however, the items do show up in the console when I console log them.

Here is my controller code:

```
exports.getShop = (req, res, next) => {

Product.find(products => {
    res.render('shop/shop',{
        products: products,
        path:'/shop',
        pageTitle:'Shop'            
    })

})
.then(products => {
    console.log(products);
})
.catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
})};
```

Here is my html/ejs:

```
<% if (products) { %>
                    <div class="grid">
                        <% for (let product of products) { %>
                            <article class="card product-item">
                                <header class="card__header">
                                    <h1 class="product__title">
                                        <%= product.title %>
                                    </h1>
                                </header>
                                <div class="card__image">
                                    <img src="/<%= product.image %>" alt="<%= product.title %>">
                                </div>
                                <div class="card__content">
                                    <h2 class="product__price">$
                                        <%= product.price %>
                                    </h2>
                                    <p class="product__description">
                                        <%= product.description %>
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                                
                            </article>
                        <% } %>
                    </div>
                    <% } else { %>
                        <h1>No Products Found!</h1>
                    <% } %>
```

Like I said, the console will display the products in my db but the page output is "No Products Found!" If I change the code a bit I get an error loading the page at "products.length"

modified code:

```
<% if (products.length > 0 ) { %>
                    <div class="grid">
                        <% for (let product of products) { %>
```

The error says "Cannot read property of null".

What am I missing here?

Comment: Where are you sending the products to the HTML file?

Comment: what do you mean?  `res.render('shop/shop', { ...products: products...} should be readable by ejs, no?

Comment: Oh, I see, missed that, silly me...

Answer (score 0):

```
Product.find(query).toArray().then(products => {
res.render('shop/shop',{
    products: products,
    path:'/shop',
    pageTitle:'Shop'            
})
```

The issue is that the mongo node.js drivers' `find` function returns a cursor object, so to 'promisify' it you'll need to use the `.toArray()` function that returns a promise.

Comment: in the .find(query) method what do I input as the query? I want to find all products and then iterate through them. When I leave it empty it doesn't work, if I input .find({}) it says .toArray() is not a function

Comment: ok so instead of .toArray() I used .lean() and it works. I guess the .lean() method returns plain objects and not mongoose documents. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Glad to hear. BTW, you didn't mention using mongoose. mongoose `find()` is different than the mongo nodejs driver `find()`.